# Ansible, junja2 and setting single quotes around a value with ansible.builtin.replace

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2

I want to make sure there are single quotes around the relation_regex defined regular expression (configuring datadog postgres module with ansible).

This is what I am aiming at:

### conf.yml:

```
instances:
-   dbname: dbname
    host: localhost
    password: password
    port: 5432
    username: datadog
    relations:
      - relation_regex: '.*'
        relkind:
        - r
        - i
        - S
        - p
```

---

This is where I am with the ansible task:

---

```
- name: Properly configure any regexp expression in a configuration file
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/{{ item }}.d/conf.yaml"
    regexp: '(\s+relation_regex:)\s+(?:['']*([^'']*))'
    replace: '\g<1> ''\g<2>'''
  with_items: "{{ datadog_checks|list }}"
  notify: restart datadog-agent
```

---

Yet, this is what is produced:

---

```
.. cut ..
-      - relation_regex: .*
+      - relation_regex: '.*
.. cut ..
```

---

Ansible does not provide the ending single quote ('). Feels like a bug but perhaps there is something wrong with my lookaround regex which has odd consequences?

Versions:

```
ansible [core 2.11.1] 
  python version = 3.8.10 (default, Mar 15 2022, 12:22:08) [GCC 9.4.0]
  jinja version = 3.0.1
  libyaml = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You omitted the **next** line of that "diff" output that would have been a dead giveaway of the problem:

```
-    - relation_regex: .*
+    - relation_regex: '.*
+'
```

which indicates that your "any character except `'`" needs to be more specific, saying "any character except `'` *or* EOL characters"

```yaml
- name: Properly configure any regexp expression in a configuration file
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/{{ item }}.d/conf.yaml"
    regexp: '(\s+relation_regex:)\s+(?:['']*([^''\r\n]*))'
    replace: '\g<1> ''\g<2>'''
  with_items: "{{ datadog_checks|list }}"
  notify: restart datadog-agent
```

Also, while this isn't what you asked, you are making things harder on yourself than necessary with the single-quoted scalar containing single quoted escapes since there's *(currently)* nothing yaml-sensitive in those scalars that needs quoting:

```yaml
- name: Properly configure any regexp expression in a configuration file
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/{{ item }}.d/conf.yaml"
    regexp: (\s+relation_regex:)\s+(?:'*([^'\r\n]*))
    replace: \g<1> '\g<2>'
  with_items: "{{ datadog_checks|list }}"
  notify: restart datadog-agent
```

You'll also want to be cautious because as written your replace will fail to harmonize *existing* single quoted items, causing idempotency failures if you run that task twice

```yaml
- name: Properly configure any regexp expression in a configuration file
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "/etc/datadog-agent/conf.d/{{ item }}.d/conf.yaml"
    regexp: (\s+relation_regex:)\s+(?:'*([^'\r\n]*)'*)
    replace: \g<1> '\g<2>'
  with_items: "{{ datadog_checks|list }}"
  notify: restart datadog-agent
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the solution I was looking for. Btw, there is a reason for this madness: it is shared code I am building upon and the code block this regex modifies is created by "to_nice_yaml" which is a bit too smart about creating the yaml and throws out any quotes it deems unnecessary. But in order for the relation_regex to work, the regex must be enclosed in single quotes.

Comment: I'm glad it worked and was something simple. For clarity, I meant the single quotes in your ansible playbook snippet, which is why I followed that statement with the unescaped version for comparison

Answer (score 0):

Given the file

```yaml
shell> cat conf.yaml
 relation_regex: .*
```

the task

```yaml
    - ansible.builtin.replace:
        path: conf.yaml
        regexp: '(\s+relation_regex:)\s+''?(.*)''?'
        replace: '\1 ''\2'''
```

gives (running --check --diff options)

```yaml
--- before: conf.yaml
+++ after: conf.yaml
@@ -1 +1 @@
- relation_regex: .*
+ relation_regex: '.*'
```